# How messages are organized into thread?

Tags: mailing-list, mailman

guys.
Can anyone explain how mailing messages are organized into threads? As I understood, messages are sent always to the same email of the group. So there has to be some identifier of thread...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every Email message has a unique `Message-ID` header.

Every reply has an `In-Reply-To` and/or `References` header.

This is enough to do a topological sort and put the messages into threads.

[update]

For the gory details, see [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) (the specification for Internet mail messages).  Search for "Message-ID", "References", and "In-Reply-To".  Strictly speaking, these headers are optional because the spec uses "SHOULD" and not "MUST" when describing them.  In practice, I have never seen an Email message that did not include a Message-ID except for spam, and I have never seen a mail client that did not include one or both reply headers in replies.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I thought that it should be part of email standard, but didn't know it.